# Php artisan migrate command throws the error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new in the Laravel and I'm facing with a problem. When I run 'php migrate artisan' command it throws the following error:

[image: 1]

I looked at almost all references, my .env and database.php files seem to look correct, also uncomment the ;extension=php_mssql.dll in php.ini file but nothing of that helps me to solve this.

If anyone have an idea how to solve this, I'll appreciate that.

*Thank you in advance*

---

**My .env file:**

```
APP_NAME=BigDeal
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:yNSvLI8gQ1vQdxFByAfz+jPhuLKy9P7LwqDVoCiLXQ8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bigdeal-laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

---

**My database.php file:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Comment: can you try with `'default' => 'mysql',` instead of `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),` ?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't solved my issue. Appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

This cause because of many reason. One of them is php extensions (like: pdo, ....).

May be the version of laravel you are using not compatible with version of php you are using in your system.

e.g: You are using laravel 5.5 which requires

- PHP >= 7.0.0
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

But your system has php 5.6 or any other lower. Which haven't these extensions.

Comment: Also seems to need the PDO + SQLite part.

Comment: I get the point, I've run 'php artisan --version' command and I can see that Laravel  version is 5.8.19 while version of my php is  7.3.5. Perhaps, this produces a issue.

Comment: I'm trying right now to fix it and will let you know what happened. Thanks a lot for clarifying.

Comment: Hmm, php info shows me following:
PDO support => enabled,
Open SSL support => enabled,
Tokenizer support => enabled,
XML PHP support => enabled